# Can't startup Bitgo on Windows

Tags: blockchain, bitgo

After installing bitgoJS, I cd into the bin directory and run the below command

bitgo-express --debug --port 3080 --env test --bind localhost I got,

'bitgo-express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclosure: I'm a Software Engineer at BitGo.*

You can find a guide for running BitGo Express in the corresponding module directory:

https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/tree/master/modules/express

Please direct further questions to the BitGo support team via email to support@bitgo.com.